# i want to refresh my all div available on my html page i.e by tag and i have 2 codes how can imerge

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

these are my 2 codes which i want to merge on each other and i want to refresh all of the div present on my page and founded that its easy method is to refresh it by tag name only but not getting how to do that  my codes are ----->>>

my html--->

```
<div class="class">
<h1>hi</h1>
</div>

<div class="class2">
<h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

code for colouring all my div by tag name ----

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
document.write(x);
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
```

code for ->>>autorefresh single div by it's id in each second------

```
    var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
   $("div").each(function(){
      $(this).load(this.href);
   })
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i want to refresh my all div by one js function only i.e possible by only using getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

try to refresh by id or class of div and set the same id to both div

```
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("sameclass");
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){ 
  (d).load(this.href);
}, 1000);
```

this might work

Comment: actullyi want to refresh all of the div's if i have 100 div in 1 page

Comment: try setting the same class about all of them manually (do not add any css style on that class that may effect your style)